# Uipagecontrol customization in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, customization, uipagecontrol

I am trying to add different views on the  pages of a uipagecontroller.Have total of three pages.That is in the first page i have to implement a map,in the second view,a simple view with some labels and the in the third view,a table.I followed the tutorial available here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html for implementing the page controller.How can i set the views of this controller based on the selected page.?Can anyone give some idea?I tried with this method.But it didn't give any way

```
    - (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
        NSLog(@"%d",page);

        if (page < 0)
            return;
        if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
            return;

        // replace the placeholder if necessary
        MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
        if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
        {
            controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
            [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
            [controller release];
      }

        // add the controller's view to the scroll view
        if (controller.view.superview == nil)
        {
            CGRect frame = scroll.frame;
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            controller.view.frame = frame;
            [scroll addSubview:controller.view];
        }
}
```

Comment: "i set the views of this controller based on the selected page" what does this mean?

Comment: There are a lot of sample cde and examples on custompage control.You should first look at them.

Comment: Any other issues @alpz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your required views to scrollView Object, and then you can manage all views by using this code:
https://github.com/SIMHAM/DDPageControl